# gcc AtomicBuiltins strange behavior in gcc 4.1.1

Tags: c++, c, gcc

In gcc doc the link [gcc-doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) I see gcc version 4.1.1 has the atomic builtins functions.

in my project ,we use gcc 4.1.1 in centos5.0,then after compile our project runs well after centos5.0. Here is my test code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static int count = 0;

void *test_func(void *arg)
{
    int i=0;
    int result = 0;
    for(i=0;i<2000;++i)
    {
        __sync_add_and_fetch(&count,1);
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t id[10];
    int i = 0;

    for(i=0;i<10;++i){
        pthread_create(&id[i],NULL,test_func,NULL);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;++i){
        pthread_join(id[i],NULL);
    }
    //10*2000=20000
    printf("%u\n",count);

    return 0; 
}
```

when I change the funciton to this things change:

```
void *test_func(void *arg)
{
    int i=0;
    int result = 0;
    for(i=0;i<2000;++i)
    {
       result = __sync_add_and_fetch(&count,1);
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

gcc -g -o code code.c  -lpthread
```

then the compile goes wrong with :undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'   I don't know why it's wrong.

now I want to use function :__sync_val_compare_and_swap,here is a demo from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140536/g-cas-sync-val-compare-and-swap-problem-needs-explaining)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

volatile bool lock;
void *locktest( void *arg )
{
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; ++i )
    {
        // acquire a lock
        while( __sync_val_compare_and_swap( &lock, false, true ) == true )
        {
            // Spin while we don't acquire
        }

        // make sure we have the lock
        assert( lock == true );

        // release the lock
        assert( __sync_val_compare_and_swap( &lock, true, false ) == true );
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

here is the wrong compile with :
/root/library/demo/sync_val_compare.c:14: undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_1' /root/library/demo/sync_val_compare.c:23: undefined reference to` __sync_val_compare_and_swap_1'

I do not know why？ something I understand wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If a particular `__sync` function cannot be supported on the target architecture, GCC treats it as an extern function (in case you want to provide an implementation). If it does this, it appends the element size; that's where the `4` is coming from. Your chosen target architecture does not seem to support atomic `add_and_fetch` on 4-byte types (which makes me suspect it doesn't support atomic intrinsics at all). Using the `-march` compiler option to force a particular architecture may help; try just `-march=native` and see if that's sufficient.

BTW, for GCC versions that support them, you should use [the `__atomic` intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) instead of the `__sync` intrinsics. The `__atomic` intrinsics give you better control over memory order guarantees, potentially improving performance. (Both sets of intrinsics exhibit the same problem when you try to use them on an architecture which doesn't support them, though.)

Comment: I use the gcc -g -o sync_val_compare sync_val_compare.c -lpthread -march=i686   then compile well,use uname -m  ouput i686,Here is a question ,my project has to compile in 32bit and 64bit for the same code.

Comment: use -march=native compile goes wrong ,then I use -march=i686 things goes well,I wonder if there some document for these gcc functions.

Comment: add -march=native,then got the wrong messages:bad value (native) for -march= switch, I use -march=i686 instead compile goes well ,As for your advice to use __atomic intrinsics,I saw the doc in gnu,it needs gcc version after 4.8.5,well my gcc version is 4.1.1